# Unable to connecto to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, appharbor

Trying to connect to mongoDB using MongoLab AddOn, I get the following error:

```
{ "$err" : "not authorized for query on myAppDB.Users", "code" : 13 }
```

when I run the following code:

```
private string connectionString = "mongodb://appharbor_93126661-e8b7-4986-958c-74e4ed8401e6:qj0boq192osh10rXXXXXXXX@ds027521.mongolab.com:27521/appharbor_93126661-e8b7-4986-958c-74e4ed8401e6";
private string dbName = "myAppDB";
private string userCollectionName = "Users";

private MongoCollection<User> GetUsersCollection()
{
      MongoUrl url = new MongoUrl(connectionString);
      MongoClient client = new MongoClient(url);
      mongoServer = client.GetServer();
      MongoDatabase database = mongoServer.GetDatabase(dbName);
      MongoCollection<User> userCollection = database.GetCollection<User>(userCollectionName);
      return userCollection;
}
```

I tried to connect from shell running the command:

```
mongo ds027521.mongolab.com:27521/appharbor_93126661-e8b7-4986-958c-74e4ed8401e6 -u appharbor_93126661-e8b7-4986-958c-74e4ed8401e6 -p qj0boq192osh10rXXXXXXXX
```

but also haven't managed to connect.

If anyone encountered similar issue or knows what is causing the problem I would be very thankful for any suggestion in prder to solve the problem.

Comment: Based on the URL you have, I think the database name (dbName) should be appharbor_93126661-e8b7-4986-958c-74e4ed8401e6.